# SQL: Reduce the size of result set

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT p.Distributor, SUM(r.SalesVolume) as Sales, 
((Cast(SUM(r.SalesVolume) as decimal(14, 4)) / (SELECT SUM(r.SalesVolume) FROM RawData r)) * 100) as MarketSharesVolume
FROM RawData r
INNER JOIN Product p
ON r.ProductId = p.ProductId
WHERE p.Distributor in ('TF1','WARNER')
GROUP BY p.Distributor;
```

The result for the above query is:

```
Distributor    Sales    MarketSharesVolume
  WARNER      2836192   58.131470300744400
  TF1         268668    5.506702600797200
```

Basically I want the `MarketSharesVolume` to have a  values like `58.1`
I tried changing the precision `decimal(14, 4)` but every other combination giver me an `Arithmetic Overflow error`.
Is there a way I could truncate the column?

Comment: You can use some function for your issue. Just have a look at this article. http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1589/sql-server-rounding-functions--round-ceiling-and-floor/

Comment: wrap `((Cast(SUM(r.SalesVolume) as decimal(14, 4)) / (SELECT SUM(r.SalesVolume) FROM RawData r)) * 100)` in [`ROUND`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175003.aspx)

Comment: @ughai Tried that but the result I get is `58.10000000000000`

Comment: you'll need to add a `convert` as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert data type of the column:

```
       SELECT p.Distributor, SUM(r.SalesVolume) as Sales, 
    CAST( (Cast(SUM(r.SalesVolume) as decimal(14, 4)) / (SELECT SUM(r.SalesVolume) FROM RawData r)) * 100 
   as decimal(20,1)) as MarketSharesVolume
    FROM RawData r
    INNER JOIN Product p
    ON r.ProductId = p.ProductId
    WHERE p.Distributor in ('TF1','WARNER')
    GROUP BY p.Distributor;
```

Answer (score 1):

[Here is an example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9eecb7/1345). Using `ROUND()` to get the correct value and `CONVERT()` to get rid of trailing zeros. You can apply this to your query.

```
DECLARE @Val DECIMAL(28, 18) = 58.131470300744400
SELECT CONVERT(decimal(28, 1), ROUND(@Val, 1))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SQL Server 2012 or above you can even use `FORMAT` like this.

```
DECLARE @v DECIMAL(18,9) = 234.234342345

SELECT @v,FORMAT(@v,'.00'),CAST(@v as DECIMAL(18,2))
```